# Terminal server client's printers load slowly

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server

A user's workstation has five printers installed. When she logs on to the terminal server (win2003 r2 sp2 x64), it takes five minutes for all the printers to become available in her terminal server session.

Her WinXP workstation uses RDP 5.2. Only the printer drivers are loaded on the terminal server, so we're using RDP's printer re-direction. No third party apps are involved.

The printers types are HP4100, HP4250 and HP4200. They are networked in her office in Oklahoma; the terminal server is located in Illinois.

Dozens of users with similar setups connect to this terminal server, but she's the only one experiencing this problem.

Comment: Is the user attempting to connect while bringing networked printers with her, that are less-than-local? (i.e. has she mapped to another printer in another office, or at home that's attempting to connect?)

Comment: Her printers are all networked. She's in Oklahoma and the term serv is in Illinois. Same domain, though. Only the printer drivers are loaded on the term serv, so we're using RDP's printer re-direction. No third party apps are involved. Sadly, win2008 isn't an option.

Comment: Once the computer final loads, are the printers there and do they actually print? Any errors related to the user found in Event Viewer?

Comment: After the user's terminal session desktop is up, it takes another five minutes for all the printers to appear. No errors in the logs. The printers do function properly.

Comment: This suggestion sucks and I know that, but is it possible for you to delete print drivers and re-install print drivers one at a time on the client machine and see if one in particular is holding up the process or if it is the entire print re-direction? I know this would be a pain, so would understand if you didn't do it. Also making the printer just offline still has it map to the TS server. Tried it on my setup. Sorry.

Comment: Her RDP was updated and so were her printer drivers. It may come down to one of those re-install her workstation deals.

Comment: I agree, it does seem to be headed that way

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to add a registry key on the client PC that will result in only the default printer being mapped on login.  This might help isolate the problem to a specific printer driver.  If one driver (installed on the server) is the problem, replacing that driver with a newer one or with HP's Universal driver might help.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911913 - hotfix should not be required, skip to "How to modify the registry"

Comment: Thank you kindly for the info. I can't convince the user to allow me to allow this reg hack.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some kind of agressive power saving on the printers?  I can conceive of situations where that, combined with driver settings, could cause this.